# Get list of members of type GROUP from Microsoft graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following code to get members of *ONLY* **'Group'** type from a group using Microsoft Graph:

```
   
    var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>() 
    { 
       new QueryOption("$count", "true") 
    }; 
    var r = await  _graphServiceClient.Groups["id"].TransitiveMembers["microsoft.graph.group"].Request(queryOptions).Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual").GetAsync(); 
    r.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@odata.count", out object count); 
    r.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("value", out object value);
```

how do I get the list of groups from *value* *object*?

Comment: It seems like some of your question didn't get posted.

Answer (score 0):

**Update :**

There was some info missing from your question and i saw your updated question , and understand that you want list of groups from value object. you can achieve this by iterating the list of group and add to different array, please check  the image below , similar question - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/288982/converting-from-api-to-sdk-c-unable-to-query-micro.html

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

    var group = await graphClient.Groups["id"].MemberOf
        .Request()
        .Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
        .GetAsync();
```

Ref doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example

[image]

hope this will help .

Comment: Thank you! This will return all members and I need to do some filtering to get only members of 'GROUP' type. I want only 'GROUP' type members.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for updating the question , now it make sense ,please check my updated Ans

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code: var group = await graphClient.Groups["id"].MemberOf
        .Request()
        .Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
        .GetAsync(); but it is giving incorrect response. Returning groups that are not a member of the actual group. What I am looking for is if I provide a group id, I need all members of type 'Group' as output

Comment: Hi thanks for the update , if you see my code , group id is provided by the group object that you are getting and based on that its collecting all the members , the best way for you to debug the code to check what you are getting on object . at the same time you can also check the same in graph explore. if you are getting the data that you want to achieve , because there might be case that group object is empty. hope this make sense , Thanks